# Firefox file chooser - choose another?

Tags: firefox, kde

I use Firefox on Linux with KDE. In any KDE application, whatever file chooser appears for opening/saving files allows me to select from more locations than Firefox's chooser, e.g. my Google Drive, or automatic searches for various file types across the file system. Is there any way to tell Firefox to use the "native" KDE chooser instead of its own?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to change just the file chooser – it gives the app a *path* to the file, but the app still needs to know how to access it. As Firefox is not written using KDE's Qt/Kio libraries, it wouldn't be able to access any virtual locations provided through Kio which don't physically exist in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I had it set up on my Arch system, which had KDE Plasma Desktop Environment. I did it about 5 years ago, so i'm afraid i don't recall the precise steps i personally used - but i followed what was in the Arch Wiki. I fairly recently installed Nobara KDE and copied my Firefox profile across. When i did, i seemed to retain the KDE File Picker automatically. I don't know, but maybe there's fewer steps depending on the distro you're using.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firefox#KDE_integration

To bring the KDE look to GTK applications (including Firefox), install breeze-gtk and kde-gtk-config. Afterwards, go to System Settings and in Appearance > Application Style > Configure GNOME/GTK Application Style… choose 'Breeze'.

To use the KDE file selection and print dialogs in Firefox 64 or newer, install xdg-desktop-portal and xdg-desktop-portal-kde, then set widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.mime-handler to 1 in about:config. You should also change widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker from 2 to 1.

For integration with KDE MIME type system, proxy and file dialog, one can use firefox-kde-opensuseAUR variant from AUR with OpenSUSE’s patches applied. Alternatively, integration with MIME types can be achieved by creating a symbolic link to the MIME database ~/.config/mimeapps.list from the deprecated ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list that is used by Firefox. See XDG MIME Applications#mimeapps.list.

Extensions/add-ons may provide additional integration, such as:
Browser integration in Plasma: requires plasma-browser-integration and the Plasma Integration add-on.